# How can I set LilyPond's "Point and Click" from Skim to VSCode?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, software, lilypond, mac

I'm working on on MacOS High Sierra, and I'm trying to use Point and Click so that Skim (PDF viewer) redirects to a specific file/line/column/character/letter/whatever on VSCode.

I've found a couple of useful resources at the LilyPond's public mailing list and some other places, but I haven't got to where I want.

Mailing list thread: https://lists.libreplanet.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2018-07/msg00039.html

Usually when clicking on a URI element on the PDF it opens LilyPond.app, but I need it to work with VSCode.

I tried some things with SwiftDefaultApps, but nothing seems to change too much.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Not so relevant, but I'm the Author of [VSLilyPond](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lhl2617.vslilypond), and I'm currently working on this feature--I'll come back after I solve it :)

Comment: Man, I just checked this questions again after some months, and dude, thank you so much! I was dying to make this work. I owe you one.